# He was injured in the accident vs he was injured at the accident

Tags: grammar, word-usage

Does anyone tell me the difference between these two sentences below?
He was injured in the accident vs he was injured at the accident.

As for a non-native speaker, it seems to me these sentences are almost similar,
except for one thing-preposition "in" and "at".

Is there any different shade of meaning?

"I saw him at the car accident scene." would be better than " I saw him in the car accident." I don't know the reason why the former sounds right to me. Anyway, if any native speaker would explain the difference, I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 3):

"At" indicates that he was present at the *location* of the accident; you woulnt say you were "at" an accident, but rather at the *scene* of the accident. "In" indicates that he was involved in the accident.

So let's say that John was driving a car and another car drove into his. You'd say:

> John was **in** an accident.

If he was hurt, your say:

> John was hurt **in** the accident.

In a different scenario, John is not a part of the accident, but happens to be at the location it occurred. You might say:

> John is **at** the scene of the accident.

If he got hurt, you similarly use "at:"

> John twisted his ankle while **at** the accident scene.

The reason behind the distinction between "accident" and its location, is that the accident has no inherent location. Obviously it happens *somewhere*, but when talking about "the acciden," you're talking about the occurrence and not the location. This is also found when you talk about the crash scene/site, crime scene, etc.